# AngularJS: Pegar valor do input no keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Já estou detectando quando o usuário aperta *enter* no *input*, mas como posso fazer para capturar o texto que ele digitou?

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app="Insidetv" ng-controller="ListaController">
     @foreach($listas as $lista)
          <input value="{{ $lista->descricao }}" type="text" name="descricao" ng-keypress="editName($event)">
     @endforeach    
</div>
```

*JS*

```
angular.module('Insidetv')
   .controller('ListaController', function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.editName = function($event){
        var keyCode = $event.which || $event.keyCode;

        if(keyCode === 13) {
             console.log($event);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

segue o exemplo

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const app = angular.module('Insidetv', []);

        app.controller('ListaController', [
            '$scope',
            function($scope) {
                $scope.editName = function($event, model) {
                    var keyCode = $event.which || $event.keyCode;

                    if (keyCode === 13) {
                        console.log(model);
                        console.log($event);
                    }
                };

            }
        ]);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="ListaController">
        <input type="text" name="descricao" ng-model="$scope.model" ng-keypress="editName($event,$scope.model)">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O input tá dentro de um foreach, então tem vários deles, como posso capturar o valor apenas do que eu to escrevendo?

Comment: coloque o resto do codigo

Comment: Pronto, editei a pergunta. Basicamente o input esta dentro de um foreach.

Comment: @DiegoVieira substitua o forEach por ng-repeat, com `track by $index`. Seu `$scope` terá uma variável do tipo array com cada valor dos inputs. Então cada input poderá ter no `ngModel` uma expressão do tipo `$scope.model[$index]`